# Group json data by a property - vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a JSON I would like to re-arrange my data, so that I can group all items by category name. Here is my data.

```
[
  {
    "id":317,
    "name":"Ingram's Camphor Cream",
    "slug":null,
    "product_category_id":15,
    "industry_id":2,
    "deleted_at":null,
    "category":{
      "id":15,
      "name":"Skincare",
      "slug":null,
      "industry_id":2,
      "deleted_at":null,
      "sku_id":3,
      "is_active":1
    },
  },
  {
    "id":323,
    "name":"Zimgold",
    "slug":null,
    "product_category_id":2,
    "industry_id":2,
    "category":{
      "id":2,
      "name":"Cooking Oils",
      "slug":null,
      "industry_id":2,
      "sku_id":2,
      "is_active":1
    }
  }
]
```

I would like to have a result like so:

```
[
   'Skincare': [ {}],
   'Cooking Oils': [{}]
]
```

Thank you in advance. I would really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reduce the array of products to a map of names to product arrays with a reducer like this:

```js
const grouped = products.reduce((grouped, product) => {
  const key = product.category.name
  // replace the array at [key] with a new one including the current element
  return { ...grouped, [key]: (grouped[key]??[]).concat(product)}
}, {})
```

Comment: Thanks but how do i make the result an array rather than an object.

Comment: I assumed the square brackets were a typo, since arrays don't have string keys. If you want to iterate over all groups, you can use `Object.entries(grouped)`. This will return an array of `[key: string, value: Product[]]` pairs.

Comment: I submitted an edit suggestion for what I thought was a typo in your result example before I read your comment. Could you make some minor edit to your question so my suggestion gets rejected automatically?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe there is a a prettier way but something like this would work

```
 var groupedData = {};

    data.forEach(item => {
        if (!groupedData[item.category.name]) {
            groupedData[item.category.name] = [];
        }
        groupedData[item.category.name].push(item);
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

```
arr.map(item=>{
    let key = item.category.name
    return {[key]:item}
})
```